# Get a list of all URLs on the Internet that match a regex

Tags: regex, web-crawler

I would like to get a list of all URLs on the Internet that match a regular expression.

E.g. I'd like to know all the unique page URLs under site:jobs.lever.co that return a 200 OK.  E.g. https://jobs.lever.co/reddit is a good result, https://jobs.lever.co/reddit?utm_source=fff and https://jobs.lever.co/bl4hbl4h are bad results.

Any tips/tricks for getting this data?  Thank you!

Comment: Do you already have a list of the available urls and just want to test if they return 200 OK ? or you want to get the list as well ?

Comment: I do not have a list of available URLs.  That's 99% of the problem, I want to know what the URLs are.

Comment: Have you considered using probably a site map generator and then get that list of all the urls ?
https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) if you're looking for a brilliant crawler (in python) and willing to invest some time for the fine tuning. It uses a combination of xPath and CSS queries.
A possible spider could look like the following code:

```
import scrapy

class leverSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lever'
    start_urls = (
        'https://jobs.lever.co/reddit',
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        # get all links
        for link in response.xpath("//a[@class='posting-title']/@href").extract():
            # do sth. with the link, e.g. parse the item
            yield scrapy.Request(link, self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # do sth. useful with your link here
```

You would start it like `scrapy crawl lever`, it searches for links with the class `posting-title` and requests these pages as well.